# "Android" missing in my "Eclipse Juno 4.1" preferences

Tags: android, eclipse

actually i downloaded "Eclipse Juno 4.1" but can't give Android SDK path because it doesn't have "Android" option in "Preferences" menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you install android plugin for eclipse?

Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software....
Click Add, in the top-right corner.
In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Answer (score 2):

I know its a stupid question, but did you install Android Development Tools into your Eclipse Juno installation from http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html?

PS.: Eclipse Juno should be 4.2; Eclipse Indigo corresponds to 4.1 as far as I know.

Comment: According to the Juno download page (http://eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php) Juno should be version 4.2. The only possible (but improbable) solution is that some version numbers weren't increased, so you might have seen this inconsistency in version numbering.

Comment: but i downloaded this one exactly about which you are talking and from the very same page as well.

Comment: OK, you were right. I downloaded the same version now. It really is 4.2, just the branding plug-ins have not been updated to state that. So the About page and the splash screen still says 4.1. Sorry about the confusion, I did not know this.

Answer (score 0):

You should update you'r eclipse to Eclipse Juno 4.2, follow this step
Click "Help" => "Check for Updates"
The Eclipse automaticly update version to Juno 4.2

then finish, Now you must follow this step for update eclipse plugin
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.2