# No Android Project option on Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Alright, same problem as here: ["Android" missing in my "Eclipse Juno 4.1" preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928769/android-missing-in-my-eclipse-juno-4-1-preferences)

But in my case, i already had the ADT installed ( i think?)[image: ADT is installed]

But, when I go to preferences or start a new project, there is no option related to android, what could i possibly did wrong?

[image: Preferences]

[image: New project window]

Comment: Using Juno on Mac and having no problems. Maybe try a clean install of Eclipse?

Comment: tried it, its still not there, :(

Comment: i already had the ADT installed ( i think?)ndon't think too much. go and conform it.

Comment: @PadmaKumar, it is installed, as you can see on the screenshot. I wasn't sure before because of the problem that i described.

and to the one who downvoted the question, may i know why? why not at least leave a comment so that i know what to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i got it to work, even though i am not too sure which one did the trick, but what I  did is change everything to 32-bit version (I was using 64-bit version). This includes the uninstalling JDK and eclipse and re-installing the 32-bit version of them (and of course, restarting the computer, even though i did this before).
It is working now, but I'm not sure if it was the re-installing of JDK or switching to 32-bit version that solves the problem.

Comment: you were not just missing the ADT plugins for eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Just uninstall the Android packages in eclipse and then re-install them, this likely occurred because the Eclipse packages were being installed whilst or before the `Android SDK` was downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the android sdk before installing the plugin in Eclipse?

Is what I do yesterday and it works. First install de sdk and later install the plugin in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, very helpful :-). I tried a lot of things ... I used the Classic version instead of the JavaEE one, tried Indigo instead of Juno ... set a different JDK ... but in my case eventually downloading the 64-bit version of Eclipse did the trick! So maybe the JDK and Eclipse must be compatible somehow ...

Answer (score 0):

After some distress I found it under *File* -> *New* -> *Other* -> *Android* from the menubar. Now to figure out how to get it under the *New* menu directly.

Comment: Questioner was print-screened this dialog.